# How can I know if a view is called multiple times?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm using laravel 5.2. In a current view, how can I know if this view is called before? Any suggestions?

Update:

Here's the scenario, I have a script in a view, and I want to run it once: the first time the view got called.

Comment: use view counter, if called, count=count+1;

Comment: Do you mean you want to keep track of how many times the page has been loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to solved this by myself. This javascript code will run once the first time the view got called:

```
@if (! $__env->yieldContent('some_section_script'))
    @section ('some_section_script')
        <script type="text/javascript">
            console.log('Hello world');
        </script>
    @stop

    @yield('some_section_script')
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a bundle package called [Laravel Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) that will show you list of views each time they are call at the current request. See below.

[image]

**For Update:**

You can share var in the view:

```
View::share('someViewCount', 0);
```

Then in the view file in the begining:

```
<?php
     if ($someViewCoutn > 0 ) {
         return;
     }
     $someViewCoutn++
?>
// rest of blade tebplate
```